# How do you merge a list of dictionaries with duplicate values to create a nested dict?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of the form:

```
[
    {
        "group_name": "CUSTOMER_RED",
        "interface": "ae4",
        "unit_name": 2520
    },
    {
        "group_name": "CUSTOMER_RED",
        "interface": "ae4",
        "unit_name": 4091
    },
    {
        "group_name": "CUSTOMER_BLUE",
        "interface": "ae4",
        "unit_name": 847
    },
    {
        "group_name": "CUSTOMER_BLUE",
        "interface": "ae4",
        "unit_name": 103
    }
}
```

How can I merge it to form a list like:

```
[
    {
        "group_name": "CUSTOMER_RED",
        "interface": "ae4",
        "unit_names": [2520, 4091]
    },
    {
        "group_name": "CUSTOMER_BLUE",
        "interface": "ae4",
        "unit_names": [847, 103]
    },
}
```

or if it is easier:

```
[
    {
        "group_name": "CUSTOMER_RED",
        "interfaces": ["ae4": "unit_names": [2520, 4091]]
    },
    {
        "group_name": "CUSTOMER_BLUE",
        "interface": ["ae4": "unit_names": [847, 103]]
    },
}
```

I tried this:

```
def merge_relevant_config(config):
    return_config = []
    for item in config:
        name = item['group_name']
        interface = item['interface']
        units = []
        for item in config:
            if item['group_name'] == name and item['interface'] == interface:
                units.append(item['unit_name'])
        return_config.append({
            'name': name,
            'interface': interface,
            'units': units
        })
    return return_config
```

However this returns duplciates:

```
[
    {
        "name": "CUSTOMER_RED",
        "interface": "ae4",
        "units": [
            2520,
            4091
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "CUSTOMER_RED",
        "interface": "ae4",
        "units": [
            2520,
            4091
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "CUSTOMER_BLUE",
        "interface": "ae4",
        "units": [
            847,
            103
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "CUSTOMER_BLUE",
        "interface": "ae4",
        "units": [
            847,
            103
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Sorry was just adding that

Answer (score 5):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
data = [
    {
        "group_name": "CUSTOMER_RED",
        "interface": "ae4",
        "unit_name": 2520
    },
    {
        "group_name": "CUSTOMER_RED",
        "interface": "ae4",
        "unit_name": 4091
    },
    {
        "group_name": "CUSTOMER_BLUE",
        "interface": "ae4",
        "unit_name": 847
    },
    {
        "group_name": "CUSTOMER_BLUE",
        "interface": "ae4",
        "unit_name": 103
    }
]

result = {}
for i in data:
    if i['group_name'] not in result:
        #if group by `group_name` & `interface` use --> result[(i['group_name'], i['interface'])]
        result[i['group_name']] = {'group_name': i['group_name'], 'interface': i['interface'], "unit_names": [i['unit_name']]}
    else:
        result[i['group_name']]["unit_names"].append(i['unit_name'])

print(list(result.values()))
```

**Output:**

```
[
    {
        'group_name': 'CUSTOMER_RED',
        'interface': 'ae4',
        'unit_names': [2520, 4091]
    },
    {
        'group_name': 'CUSTOMER_BLUE',
        'interface': 'ae4',
        'unit_names': [847, 103]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answer does not take in to account multiple interfaces, this example does:

```
def merge_config(config):
    merged = []
    sets = {}
    for item in config:
        as_text = '{}-{}'.format(item['group_name'], item['interface'])
        if as_text in sets.keys():
            sets[as_text].append(item['unit_name'])
        else:
            sets[as_text] = [item['unit_name']]

    for k, v in sets.items():
        group_name, interface = k.split('-')
        merged.append(
            {
                'group_name': group_name,
                'interface': interface,
                'unit_names': v
            }
        )
   return merged
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one with some versatility using [`itertools.groupy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and a custom function.  You can define the key you want to group by, and without knowing the inner keys you can still fully merge the dictionaries:

```
from itertools import groupby

def merge_dicts(*dcts):
    # define a merge function
    merged = {}
    for dct in dcts:
        for k, v in dct.items():            
            if merged.setdefault(k, v) != v:
                if not isinstance(merged.get(k), list):
                    merged[k] = [merged.get(k)]
                merged.get(k).append(v)
    return merged

group_key = 'group_name'
result = [merge_dicts(*grouped) for key, grouped in groupby(l, lambda dct: dct.get(group_key))]
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    'group_name': 'CUSTOMER_RED',
    'interface': 'ae4',
    'unit_name': [2520, 4091]
  },
  {
    'group_name': 'CUSTOMER_BLUE',
    'interface': 'ae4',
    'unit_name': [847, 103]
  }
]
```